# Converting a 2D List to a 3D List in Python

Tags: python

I have a List of List (2D List) in Python of dimension (2, 7) and I want to convert it to List of Lists of Lists (3D List) of dimension (2, 7, 1).

Input:

```
[[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Output:

```
[[[0],
  [0],
  [1],
  [0],
  [1],
  [0],
  [0]
 ]
 [[1],
  [0],
  [1],
  [0],
  [0],
  [0],
  [0]]]
```

How would I do it?

Comment: what did you try? what trouble do you have? what logic do you wnat to release?

Comment: I cannot think of an approach. Pretty tough.

Comment: `[[[x] for x in y] for y in lst]`

Comment: how about this? new_array=[your_list]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with a double for loop (or list comprehension), but for that kind of things it is better to use numpy

```
 import numpy as np
 x2D = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
 x3D = x2D[:, :, None]
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Is there also a way to convert this 3D numpy array to a 3D sparse matrix?

Comment: @K.K.: yes, but there various forms for sparse matrices. See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html

Comment: I tried to create the various forms of sparse matrices like coo, csr, etc from the 3D array but it says it expects a dimension 2 or less.

Comment: @K.K.mmm, right, it only supports 2D arrays. There are a few packages supporting that if you google it, nothing standard though.

Comment: Hmm..Nope I couldnt find any. I will just start a new thread. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

If you have the list

`a = [[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]`

then writing
`[[i] for i in a]`

will give you

`[[[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]], [[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]]`.

This is almost what you want, except each element needs to be a list itself. So we can modify it to (thanks Tryph!)

`[map(lambda x: [x], item) for item in a]`

which will give you

`[[[0], [0], [1], [0], [1], [0], [0]], [[1], [0], [1], [0], [0], [0], [0]]]`.

Comment: just because I don't like nested comprehensions, I would suggest `[map(lambda x: [x], item) for item in a]` which gives the same result